# Azure Subscription: using Certificate or AAD authentication on PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

I'm currently using AAD authentication for deploying some code but I'm finding that my session times out on the server, which requires me to log back in.

I heard I could use certificates to authenticate to Azure, is this the way to go or is there a different method people use?

Comment: please specify use case in detail which you are trying to achieve. Basically use of different AAD authentication methods based on use case you are trying to achieve. Also it will be easy for community to help you back.

Answer (score 0):

If your AAD authentication session times out in a short time, you could consider [configuring token lifetimes in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes).

An Powershell cmd sample:

```
$policy = New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"02:00:00","MaxAgeSessionSingleFactor":"02:00:00"}}') -DisplayName "WebPolicyScenario" -IsOrganizationDefault $false -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"
```

More samples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#example-create-a-policy-for-web-sign-in).

Comment: It doesn't really time out in a short time, but every other day a manual login is required, the idea is to use a certificate so that the VM is always connected and we can deploy from it at any time. 

I tried following this: http://itproguru.com/expert/2015/02/azure-powershell-getting-started-authenticate-with-certificate/ 

But the azure subscription are still associated with a username instead of a cert.